# Protractor failed to getText of input from list

Tags: javascript, testing, protractor, e2e-testing

I try to use Protractor to test a list of settings form.

Here is my test code :

```
describe('Settings View', function() {

  it('add data to settings', function() {
    browser.get('/#/settings');
    data_list = element.all(by.css('form[name="form_list.settings_form"] input'));
    data4 = data_list.get(3);
    data4.sendKeys('5 minutes');
    //browser.pause();
    expect(data4.getText()).toEqual('5 minutes');
    //data4.getText() equals '' <-- why ?
  });

});
```

When I uncomment **browser.pause()** line, I show the text **5 minutes** in the form. But when I run test, protractor give me an error which means that **data4.getText()** gives a **blank string**.

Do you have any idea to get the value that I defined ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `getAttribute()` function to get the text of an input element as its stored in `value` attribute, instead of using `getText()` and so you get a blank value. Here's how -

```
expect(data4.getAttribute('value')).toEqual('5 minutes');
```

Hope it helps.